# Dropdown list doesn't show up, what am i doing wrong

Tags: html, css

I'm following a [tutorial](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu) on how to make a pure css drowndown menu on hover.
After several times running it all over again I'm still stuck and hoping to get some good explanation on my problem.

```
            <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <div><a href="3d.html">3D Printing</a></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                            <div><a href="#">blah</a></div>
                            </li><li>
                            <div><a href="#">blah</a></div>
                            </li><li>
                            <div><a href="#">blah</a></div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <li>
                    <div><a href="#"></a></div>
                    </li><li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

So this is the HTML nothing wrong with that I think.

```
    .navbar ul {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: lemon;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    font-size: 210%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    }
    
    .navbar ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    }
    
    .navbar ul li {
    display: block;
    }
    
    .navbar ul ul {
    display: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 18px 5px;
    }
    
    navbar ul li:hover ul  {
    display: block;
    }
    
    .navbar ul ul li {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    }
    
    .navbar ul ul li:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)
    }
    
    .navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    }
    
    .navbar ul li a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

The problem lies somewhere in here but I can't find it, your help is much appreciated !

Thanks in advance and my sincere greetings.

Raymond The Hammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
navbar ul li:hover ul  {
display: block;
}
```

you missed a `dot` for navbar `class`

```
.navbar ul li:hover ul  {
display: block;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/0ng3axuq/)

note that, do not use `div` inside `ul li` tags!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
<div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
               <a href="3d.html">3D Printing</a>
                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .navbar ul {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: lemon;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    font-size: 210%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    }

    .navbar ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    }

    .navbar ul li {
    display: block;
    }

    .navbar ul ul {
    display: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 18px 5px;
    }

    .navbar ul li:hover ul  {
    display: block;
    }

    .navbar ul ul li {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    }

    .navbar ul ul li:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)
    }

    .navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .navbar ul li a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    }
```